# How to extract a node of XML and create a new XML document

Tags: xml, powershell, xmldocument

I need to use Powershell to extract a node (and children) from a larger XML document and create a new standalone XML document containing only the extracted XML node (and children); then I need to save this new extracted XML in a file.  The top-level XML node being extracted has attributes.  It appears that I will have to set the new XML object's XMLDocument value to do this, but XMLDocument is a read-only property.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crux is to use the `XmlDocument.ImportNode()` method e.g.:

```
$xml1 = [xml](Get-Content foo.xml)
# find the node you want to extract
$node = $xml1.Foo.Bar

$xml2 = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$newNode = $xml2.ImportNode($node, $true)
$xml2.AppendChild($newNode)
$xml2.Save("bar.xml")
```

Comment: Thank you.  Nowhere else did I find such a concise correct answer.