# Extract XML data and Save as XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, soap

I'm trying to figure out how to extract data from XML data I receive from a web service in PowerShell. I want to output it as an XML file also.

I'm using `Invoke-WebRequest` to save the file using `-Outfile`, but I don't want all the soap envelope data. From the sample data below all I want is the data in `<Visit_Requests>` in an XML format, to be later imported to a database using SSIS.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <getData_Visit_RequestsResponse xmlns="http://example.com/">
            <getData_Visit_RequestsResult RequestDate="10 Apr 2017" NumberOfRecordsReturned="54" MaximumNumberOfRecordsReturned="10000" RecordsStartAtRowNumber="1" PagingImplemented="true" ErrorMessage="">
                <Visit_Requests>
                    <Visit_Request>
                        <Visit_ID>3907</Visit_ID>
                        <Building_Name>Building HHH</Building_Name>
                        <Level_Name>North Wing</Level_Name>
                        <Contact_Name>Bill Bloggs</Contact_Name>
                    </Visit_Request>
                    <Visit_Request>
                        <Visit_ID>3904</Visit_ID>
                        <Building_Name>Building GG</Building_Name>
                        <Level_Name>South Wing</Level_Name>
                        <Contact_Name>Mary Bloggs</Contact_Name>
                    </Visit_Request>
                    <Visit_Request>
                        <Visit_ID>3970</Visit_ID>
                        <Building_Name>Building VV</Building_Name>
                        <Level_Name>East Wing</Level_Name>
                        <Contact_Name>Bob Bloggs</Contact_Name>
                    </Visit_Request>
                    <Visit_Request>
                        <Visit_ID>4707</Visit_ID>
                        <Building_Name>Building ZZ</Building_Name>
                        <Level_Name>West Wing</Level_Name>
                        <Contact_Name>Joe Bloggs</Contact_Name>
                    </Visit_Request>
                </Visit_Requests>
            </getData_Visit_RequestsResult>
        </getData_Visit_RequestsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227243/how-to-extract-a-node-of-xml-and-create-a-new-xml-document) approach but got nowhere. I keep getting errors

> Cannot import a null node

or

> [System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method named 'Save'

I've tried writing the contents to another file using

```bsh
$xmlnode | Out-File 'c:\temp\aaaatest.xml'
```

but all that gets written is a PowerShell object `{Visit_Request, Visit_Request...}`.

Code for the to get the results I wanted using `$xmlnode.OuterXml`.

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

[xml]$result = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method post -ContentType 'text/xml' -Body $SOAP_getData_Visit_Requests #-OutFile .\response.xml 

[System.Xml.XmlElement] $root = $result.get_DocumentElement()
$xmlnode = $root.Body.getData_Visit_RequestsResponse.getData_Visit_RequestsResult.Visit_Requests

$xmlnode.OuterXml| out-file ".\response.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you require `$xmlnode.InnerXml` or `$xmlnod.OuterXml`.

Please post your code as it's not clear how you are processing the XML.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I managed to get what I wanted using $xmlnod.OuterXml.